# Removing null properties from JSON Object

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

I have a JSON object like below, i want to remove all the key, value pair object from that Object. My app uses AngularJS. 
for eg below is my object

```
var items = [
{name:"Nick"},
{name:"Lee"},
{name:"Jenny"},
{name:null},
{name:null},
{name:null},
{name:"Graham"},
{name:"Erica"}]
```

I want a new object with names who has null value removed.
Are there any ready functions in Angular or Underscore js

Comment: That is not a JSON object. It is a JavaScript array. Have you tried anything? Have you read the documentation of Array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it directly in javascript

```
items.filter( i => i.name );
// or in ES5
items.filter(function(i) {return i.name});
```

This looks a bit weird as you are relying upon javascript's truthyness to render null as false, and anything else as 'true'

Comment: also looks weird if OP is only familiar with ES 5

Comment: Some other values (such as zero and empty string) are also falsey, so to answer the exact question the filter function should check if `i.name` is `null` and not rely to JavaScript's implicit conversion to boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove null and empty string values from a *json* object by below code.

I have *json* object call `sjonObj` and want remove all null and empty string.

```
sjonObj = (function filter(obj) {
    var filtered = _.pick(obj, function (v) { return v !== '' && v !== null; });
    return _.cloneDeep(filtered, function (v) { return v !== filtered && _.isPlainObject(v) ? filter(v) : undefined; });
})(sjonObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understood your question.
In case you wanted to really remove (delete) the properties out of the object you could iterate over its keys and use `delete`.

```
var obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    delete obj[key];
});

console.log(obj); // prints empty object { }
```